# How to Solve Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-middleware

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                        | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware
                                                                                  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                          |                  | Closure                                                                | web
                                                                                  |
|        | POST     | _ignition/execute-solution |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController             | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled,F
acade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionConfigValueEnabled:enableRunnableSolutions |
|        | GET|HEAD | _ignition/health-check     |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\HealthCheckController                 | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled
                                                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | _ignition/scripts/{script} |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ScriptController                      | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled
                                                                                  |
|        | POST     | _ignition/share-report     |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ShareReportController                 | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled,F
acade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionConfigValueEnabled:enableShareButton       |
|        | GET|HEAD | _ignition/styles/{style}   |                  | Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\StyleController                       | Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled
```

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? What's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a problem to solve, these are the routes of the new debugging package for Laravel 6 called `Facade/Ignition`

They are required so Laravel can show you errors when they occur

So just ignore them

However, if you want to remove these routes (which is not recommended), you can remove this line from `composer.json`

```
 "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4", <--- Remove this one
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
```

And run

```
composer update
```

But then you wouldn't see custom error pages but the default PHP7 errors table and stack trace.

You can still get the old package [filp/whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) by installing it

```
composer require filp/whoops
```

Comment: I also got this error. When I remove Facade/Ignition i get a much more accurate error screen. So why should I keep it?

Comment: Latest version of Laravel uses Flare to display errors, and it's much better IMO

Answer (score 12):

If you have a lot of `POST` request `/_ignition/execute-solution` in your production server by a random attacker and you notice that request call to the following controller and middlewares:

```
Controller  Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController
Middleware  Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionEnabled, Facade\Ignition\Http\Middleware\IgnitionConfigValueEnabled:enableRunnableSolutions
```

you have to set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` in your `.env` file instead of removing the `Facade/Ignition` package.

Comment: Can you explan a bit more @pableiros?

Comment: @StanislavStankov an attacker is trying to do "remote code execution" in the server using a exploit (sort of) from `Ignition`. For more info: https://www.ambionics.io/blog/laravel-debug-rce

Comment: Another discussion https://github.com/facade/ignition/issues/350

Comment: Is there anyway to block the following url (endpoint) with .htaccess so apache mod_rewrite module can prevent it ?

Answer (score 3):

Up to date solution for this problem:

1. Update `facade/ignition`:

`composer update facade/ignition`

2. If you don't have `config/ignition.php` then run:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ignition-config`

3. Then make this edition:

`'enable_runnable_solutions' => false,`

Comment: Does this have any side effect when using in a Laravel project?

Comment: @realtebo nothing serious unless you really used that feature for debugging. Anyway you can separately enable it in your local env. More details: https://flareapp.io/docs/ignition-for-laravel/security

Comment: where to make the edition 
'enable_runnable_solutions' => false,

Comment: @mrtechmaker in `config/ignition.php`

Answer (score 0):

put IGNITION_ENABLE_RUNNABLE_SOLUTIONS=false in .env and APP_DEBUG=false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i tried both salutions

```
1.    IGNITION_ENABLE_RUNNABLE_SOLUTIONS=false in .env and APP_DEBUG=false
2.    composer update facade/ignition
```

and still under attacks

```
local.INFO: POST /_ignition/execute-solution - Body: {"solution":"Facade\\Ignition\\Solutions\\MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution","parameters":{"variableName":"zzzz","viewFile":"php:\/\/filter\/write=convert.iconv.utf-8.utf-16le|convert.quoted-printable-encode|convert.iconv.utf-16le.utf-8|convert.base64-decode\/resource=..\/storage\/logs\/laravel.log"}} - Headers: {"host":["13.238.123.22:80"],"user-agent":["Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/78.0.3904.108 Safari\/537.36"],"connection":["close"],"content-length":["356"],"content-type":["application\/json"],"accept-encoding":["gzip"]} - Files:
```

here is my plugin version of facade/ignition

```
name     : facade/ignition
descrip. : A beautiful error page for Laravel applications.
keywords : error, flare, laravel, page
versions : * 2.17.7
```